# Can bijection between natural numbers and prime numbers be holomorphically extended to the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analysis

It is well known that we can map $n\in\mathbb N$ to the $n$-th prime number, can this map be extended holomorphically to the complex plane? If so, are there any good properties of it?

It seems an interesting question but I did not search anything related to it. Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of entire functions with this property.

Comment: @AnginaSeng are there? Can you give an example? I am out of complex-analysis business and don’t think this is obvious...

Comment: Let $f$ be your function and consider $f(z)+g(z)\sin\pi z$ for any entire $g$.

Comment: For any complex sequence $a_n\to \infty$ and any complex sequence $b_n$ there exists an entire function $f(z)$ satisfying $f(a_n)=b_n$, see [Entire function with prescribed values](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299818/152568), indeed, infinitely many of them. One can even write an explicit series for it. In your case $a_n=n$ and $b_n=p_n$. But there is no such function that gives us anything interesting, as far as I know.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thanks, that's what I wanted.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you very much, it helps me a lot! ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^{x} \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{p_n}{e^n}\frac{\sin(\pi (x-n))}{\pi (x-n)}$$
It is entire because the summand are entire and the series converges locally uniformly.

The same method works for any sequence, all we have to do is to replace $e^x, 1/e^n$ by $f(x),1/f(n)$ where $f$ is an entire function [growing fast enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Growth).