# Continuous curve for 2-adic valuation of x

Tags: trigonometry, continuity, recurrence-relations

I am trying to find a continuous curve that will go trough all the points in the graph created if you were to plot the 2-adic valuation of x which is defined as how many times you can divide a number by two before the result gives an odd number. This can be defined by the function: $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}
 &0\text{ when x is odd}\\
 f(\frac{x}{2})+1\text{ when x is even}\\
 \end{array}\right. $$
The problem with this is that I cant differentiate since I need a continuous curve, and right now this only gives me what the values go like: 0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,etc.
$$$$
What I am currently trying is to find a trigonometric function that represents it. For example $\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)}$ works for some values (just the alternating 0's and 1's) but I dont know how I could modify this to fit all values.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299818/entire-function-with-prescribed-values) explains how to do it with the Mittag-Leffler theorem, if you're familiar with that.  While the procedure given there is explicit, I don't think one could write down the formula in a very convenient way.

Comment: @reuns this looks promising, however what does $v_2(n)$ denote?

Answer (score 2):

$v_2(n)$ is the 2-adic valuation of $n$. Then look at things like

$$g(z)=e^{z^2}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}+\sum_{n\ne 0} \frac{e^{-n^2} v_2(n)}{z-n}$$ which is entire.

It gives $g(0)=0$, add $\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^3}$ if you want a meromorphic function such that $f(n)=v_2(n)$ for all $n\in \Bbb{Z}$

Comment: Doesn't this have undefined points when z is an integer?

Comment: No it is standard that $\sin(x)/x$ equals $\sin'(0)=1$ at $0$.

Comment: How could I change the equation so that it takes that into count? Because i tried and i ended up with g(z)=g(z)+the same sum you gave.